# Exit with error code from init block in Genie

Tags: genie

In Vala, I can write the following code:

```
int main(string[] args) {
    if (args[1] == "secret") {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

How would I do the same in Genie? The following does not work:

```
init
    if args[1] == "secret"
        return 0
    else
        return 1
```

… because returning a value from a void block is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present this is not possible using the `init` method. See [Bug 707233 - Allow exit status to be set from init function](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707233).

This can be achieved with GLib's [Process.exit()](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Process.exit) call:

```
[indent=4]
init
    if args[ 1 ] == "secret"
        Process.exit( 0 )
    else
        Process.exit( 1 )
```

Alternatively, if you are working in a Posix environment, compile the following with `valac --pkg posix my_exit_example.gs`:

```
[indent=4]
init
    if args[ 1 ] == "secret"
        Process.exit( Posix.EXIT_SUCCESS )
    else
        Process.exit( Posix.EXIT_FAILURE )
```

If you would like to add this to the Genie parser then look at the `parse_main_method_declaration()` method in the [vala/valagenieparser.vala](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/vala/valagenieparser.vala) source file. The syntax would have to be something like:

```
[indent=4]
init:int
    if args[ 1 ] == "secret"
        return 0
    else
        return 1
```